# JavaScriptでCSVデータが入った二次元配列をJSONにしたい

Tags: javascript, json

### 質問

以下のような二次元配列（CSVなどから取得）から、JSON形式に変換するコードを書いたのですが、車輪の再発明のような気がしてならず、質問しました。

### 期待する回答

多くの方が既に取り組まれているコードかと思っておりまして、わざわざ自分で作らなくても、既に便利な関数なりライブラリがあるんじゃないかと思います。
これをご存じであればご教示いただきたいです。
（なければないで構いません）

想像しているのは、たとえばpythonだと`zip`があるので（多少頑張る必要はありましたが）あまり気にしなかったんですが、JavaScriptで相応の関数なりライブラリがあればと思いました。

### 期待していない回答

泥臭い方法での解答コードは不要です。
mapやfilterを使うケースについては、既に動くものが手元に存在しています。

この泥臭いコードを作成していて、ふと疑問に思ったので質問させていただいているという経緯です。

**対象の二次元配列:**

```
let data = [
  ["header1", "header2", ...],
  ["content1", "content2", ...],
  ["content1", "content2", ...],
  ...
]
```

**CSVデータから変換後の(期待する)JSONデータ:**

```
let data = [
  {
    [data[0][0]]: data[1][0],
    [data[0][1]]: data[1][1],
    [data[0][2]]: data[1][2],
    ...
  }, {
  {
    [data[0][0]]: data[2][0],
    [data[0][1]]: data[2][1],
    [data[0][2]]: data[2][2],
    ...
  }, 
  ...
]
```

Comment: 検索するとこんなのが見つかるので試してみては？ [JavascriptでCSV(ヘッダー項目あり)をJSON形式に変換する方法【Underscore.js使用】](https://mameko.jp/208/) その記事で紹介されているこちら [遅すぎたUnderscore.js詳述 - Arrays編](https://qiita.com/hp0me/items/ad5530ed71a3c8ea8601) に [zip](https://qiita.com/hp0me/items/ad5530ed71a3c8ea8601#zip) というのがあるようなので、そちらを使うというのも出来るかもしれませんね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。zip相当が存在するとのことで安心しました。元データを用意するのに神経をすり減らさないようになっただけでも大変助かります。とはいえ、欲しいのはJSONなので、これは多少頑張るのは止むを得ないのかなといった所感です。引き続き意見を募集しようと思いますので、もしお気付きの方法があればまたご教示いただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 該当するかどうか不明なのと、古かったりしたので紹介しなかったこんなのもあります。[JavaScriptでCSVデータ(項目行あり)をJSON形式に変換する](http://lifelog.main.jp/wordpress/?p=2970), [CSV文字列をJSONオブジェクトに変換](https://shanabrian.com/web/javascript/csv-to-json.php) これらから使える部分を抜き出して応用することが出来るかもしれません。

Comment: 引き続きご回答いただきありがとうございます。やはり自力で頑張ろうとしたらいただいた例の通り、泥臭い書き方をするしかないですよね。というのも、最初作成していたのもこちらのやり方に近い書き方をしていましたので、当該コードがグチャグチャして嫌だなぁと思っていたところでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lodashの `zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipObject) を使えば、最小限の頑張りで実現できそうです。

```js
const { zipObject } = require("lodash");
// const zipObject = require("lodash.zipobject");
// import { zipObject } from "lodash";
// import zipObject from "lodash.zipobject";

const data = [
  ["header1", "header2"],
  ["content1.1", "content1.2"],
  ["content2.1", "content2.2"],
  ["content3.1", "content3.2"],
];

const [header, ...values] = data;
const output = values.map(value => zipObject(header, value));
console.log(output);
// [
//   { header1: 'content1.1', header2: 'content1.2' },
//   { header1: 'content2.1', header2: 'content2.2' },
//   { header1: 'content3.1', header2: 'content3.2' }
// ]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、まさに期待した回答でした！（現行コードは既にfixしてしまったため差し替えが難しくなりましたが）今後も似たような機能を作ることがあると思いますので、その際にこちらを活用していきたいと思います！